# How to simulate ReadTimeoutException in Spock with Micronaut

Tags: java, unit-testing, spock, micronaut

I am trying to simulate `io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException` with Spock, but explicitly the exception cannot be thrown, as it cannot be accessed from the test class.

The code which I want to test is given below:

```
        try {
             res = httpClient.toBlocking().exchange(
                    HttpRequest.GET(url)
                            .header("env", "internal")
                            .header("Content-Type", "application/json"),
                    TokenResponseBody.class
            );

        } catch (HttpClientResponseException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Visa Token get request", e);
            throw new CardTokenException(String.valueOf(e.getStatus().getCode()), e.getMessage());
        } catch (ReadTimeoutException re) {
            LOGGER.error("Visa Token get request", re);
            throw new CardTokenException(re.getMessage(), "Tokens client read timeout");
        }
```

So I am trying to stub the `BlockingHttpClient` which is returned by the `httpClient.toBlocking()` like this:

```
BlockingHttpClient blockingHttpClientStub = Stub(BlockingHttpClient.class)
blockingHttpClientStub.exchange(
        _ as MutableHttpRequest, TokenResponseBody.class
) >> {
      MutableHttpRequest obj, Class classType -> new Thread().sleep(15000)
}
httpClient.toBlocking() >> blockingHttpClientStub
```

the default config duration is 10 seconds, so I am assuming the `sleep` method would interrupt it for 15 seconds and ReadTimeoutException will be thrown. Please help me out if there any way to simulate the the `ReadTimeoutException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you figure that `new Thread().sleep(15000)` will block anything? You are creating a separate thread then you then try to sleep, before it even started. You can try `Thread.currentThread().sleep()`. However, you are basically replacing the whole implementation, so there is nothing to throw the exception.

Why don't you simply throw the exception?

```java
BlockingHttpClient blockingHttpClientStub = Stub(BlockingHttpClient) {
    exchange(_ as MutableHttpRequest, TokenResponseBody) >> {
        throw io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.TIMEOUT_EXCEPTION
    }
}
httpClient.toBlocking() >> blockingHttpClientStub
```